# kibana summing up terms as a whole string

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I want to sum up terms and display the count as a table. Therefore I have created a term panel and I  configured the 'field' field. The field contains values such as example-1 and example-2. When kibana creates the table, it shows me the sum for 'example' and '1' and '2'. Why does it not sum up the whole term 'example-1' and 'example-2'? Have I configured something wrongly?

Answer (score 1):

use .raw extension of field to prevent splitting of terms. "field.raw' instead of 'field'

Comment: It looks like there's a lot more needed to this answer before it will work, including specifying certain mapping configurations.